# Regular Expression to match string after ambiguous marker

Tags: regex, vba, outlook, ms-word

I'm trying to match passport numbers in emails I receive in Outlook. Basically, the marker can be any of the following formats:

Pass **1234567**

Pass, **11223344**

Pass: **1234567**

Passport # is **HA12345678**.

Passport #: **G7654321**

Passport:  **1234567** (Nepal)

Passport No **123456789**

Passport No.:    **123456789**

Passport No: **TG1234567**

Passport Number **1234567**

Passport Number - **5432198765**

passport number, **AH123456789**

Passport Number: **AB123456**

Passport/Travel Document Number: **AZ0912345**

I'm only interested in capturing the bold number part but it must be in close proximity to the Pass* label because there are other numbers in the email that could be misinterpreted as passport numbers.

I'm using VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5 under VBA (Word & Outlook) Office 2010 under Windows 7. I believe this flavor of regex is most closely related to that used in JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

## Description

This regex will match strings which start with 2 alphanumeric characters and continue with between 5 and 10 more alpha numeric characters. I'm allowing so many characters because the sample text had a range of desired string sizes.

`\b[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}[0-9]{5,10}\b`

[image]

## Input Text

your 14 lines of input sample text

```
Pass 1234567
Pass, 11223344
Pass: 1234567
Passport # is HA12345678.
Passport #: G7654321
Passport: 1234567 (Nepal)
Passport No 123456789
Passport No.: 123456789
Passport No: TG1234567
Passport Number 1234567
Passport Number - 5432198765
passport number, AH123456789
Passport Number: AB123456
Passport/Travel Document Number: AZ0912345
```

## Matches

```
[0] => 1234567
[1] => 11223344
[2] => 1234567
[3] => HA12345678
[4] => G7654321
[5] => 1234567
[6] => 123456789
[7] => 123456789
[8] => TG1234567
[9] => 1234567
[10] => 5432198765
[11] => AH123456789
[12] => AB123456
[13] => AZ0912345
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?:[A-Z 0-9]{2})[0-9]{5,10}$
```

where:

- `^` represents the starting of the string.
- `(` represents the starting of the group.

  - `?` represents the 0 or 1 time.
  - `[A-Z 0-9]{2}` represents the next two alphabets/digits should be any between A-Z/0-9.
- `)` represents the ending of the group.
- `[0-9]{5,10}` represents the next digits should be any between 0-9 and min 5 and max 10
- `$` represents the ending of the string.

Comment: The line about the `?` is wrong. It is not working as a quantifier. The `?:` means that the group is non-capturing